# What algorithm will determine if two strings match eachother or not?

Tags: substrings, edit-distance, string-matching, string-metrics, hamming-distance

$\require{enclose}$

#### Definition of *parent*

For any three strings $x$, $y$, and $p$, we say that $p$ is a ***parent*** of $x$ and $y$ if and only if all of the following:

- $p$ is a $\enclose{updiagonalstrike, downdiagonalstrike}{\text{substring}}$ sub-sequence of some permutation of the concatenation of $x$ and $y$.
- $x$ is a $\enclose{updiagonalstrike, downdiagonalstrike}{\text{substring}}$ sub-sequence of $p$
- $y$ is a $\enclose{updiagonalstrike, downdiagonalstrike}{\text{substring}}$ sub-sequence of $p$

---

#### Definition of *Match*

For any two strings $x$ and $y$, we say that $x$ and $y$ match if and only if no permutation of the shortest length parent of $x$ and $y$ is a parent of $x$ and $y$.

#### Example One

For example, the following two strings $\enclose{updiagonalstrike, downdiagonalstrike}{\text{math}}$ (Edit: actually, they do **NOT** match):

- **string 1** `"ABC INDUST INC"`
- **string 2** `"ABC INDUSTRIES"`

The following are all examples of minimum-length parent strings:

- `"ABC INDUST RINCES"`
- `"ABC INDUSTR INCES"`
- `"ABC INDUST RINCES"`
- `"ABC INDUST RIESNC"`

#### Example Two

The following two strings do **NOT** match:

- **string 3** `"IOWA"`
- **string 4** `"OHIO"`

One example of a minimum-length common super-sequence is "IOWHAIO".

Unfortunately, if we swap the letter "W" with the letter "H" then we have a new string which is also common super-sequence of "IOWA" and "OHIO"

If any permutation of a minimum length parent string is also a parent string, then the two child strings do not match.

Two strings match each-other if and only if the minimum length parent string is unique.

---

What is an example of an algorithm which will determine if two strings match each-other or not?

As input, the algorithm accepts an ordered pair of two strings.

The output of the algorithm is a boolean, true or false.

---

An answer to this question could simply be the name of an algorithm provided that there exists a Wikipedia page on that algorithm. Otherwise your answer should be code or pseudo-code.

Any algorithm which gets the job done is a valid answer to this question. However, an efficient algorithm is likely to garner more up votes than an inefficient one.

---

For any two strings $x$ and $y$ we define a ***good parent*** of $x$ and $y$ to be any super-string of $x$ and $y$ such that no permutation of the good parent is a super-string of $x$ and no permutation of the goof parent is a super string of $y$.

Strings $x$ and $y$ match if and only if there exists a good parent of $x$ and $y$.

---

**EDIT**:  Everywhere I wrote "sub-string" I should have written "sub-sequence"

---

We do **not** want to use the [Levenstien Distance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

---

Comment: Terminology: I would not say that IOWA is a substring of IOWHAIO.

Comment: I agree with @YvesDaoust, did you perhaps mean "subsequence" instead of "substring"?

Comment: Your definition of 'match' implicitly assumes that every pair of strings $x,y$ has a unique shortest length parent, but this is false: consider two strings $x=$"HI", $y=$"LO", which have two shortest length parents, "HILO" and "LIHO".  Please [edit] your definition to revise the definition of 'match' to clarify what to do in this kind of situation.

Comment: Your definition of 'match' can't be right.  The identity permutation is a permutation, so it is impossible to satisfy the criterion "no permutation of the shortest length parent of x and y is a parent of x and y".  There always exists such a permutation (indeed, the identity permutation qualifies).

Comment: In which course is this an exercise?

Comment: @reinierpost My question was not a ho.eqork exercise in any high school or college course. I realize that my question was niave, but I graduated from college more than 5 years ago. I received a bachelor's degree only and never went into research. I do not have a masters or Ph.D Also, it was a low quality state school; not one I would reccomend attending. Additionally, my last job was stocking shelves at a grocery store, and other jobs have been similarly non-intellectual. It is safe to say that my computer science skills are rusty.

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon I asked because it's such an excellently crafted question.

Comment: @YvesDaoust `IOWA` is a ***sub-sequnce*** of `IOWHAIO` I mistakenly wrote that `IOWA` is a ***sub-string*** of `IOWHAIO`

Comment: @Nathaniel I meant "sub-sequence" instead of "sub-string"

Comment: Rather than writing incorrect things and then crossing them out, please edit the post to only state correct things, and remove all of the incorrect statements.  No need to preserve the original version.  Similarly for "EDIT:".  We want the question to read well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  Once you've done that, I encourage you to go through comments and flag them as 'no longer needed' once they ahve been addressed by the edit.